# Assistance with msaccess sql query

Tags: sql, ms-access, filtering

I have a form called “Search” with the question regarding the section under Transaction Search.  It invokes a query based on the selection of full name (Combo40) which pulls from a table called “Individuals” and the committee(s) the user selected in Combo40 has contributed to in the Committee field:

Committee Query:

```
SELECT Transactions.[Committee Name] FROM Transactions GROUP BY Transactions.[Committee   Name], Transactions.[Employee Name] HAVING (((Transactions.[Employee Name])=[Forms]![Search]![Combo40]));
```

I’m trying to add an additional parameter that also compares the year in which an individual gave which is a specific filed in the Transactions table called Combo46.

New Query:

```
SELECT Transactions.[Committee Name] FROM Transactions GROUP BY Transactions.           [Committee Name], Transactions.[Employee Name] HAVING (((Transactions.[Employee Name])=Forms!Search!Combo40) And (((Transactions.Combo46)=Forms!Search!Combo51)))

Forms!Search!Combo40 = pulls the values from a table called “Individuals”
Transactions.Combo46 = year (i.e. 2011, 2012, 2013 etc.)
Forms!Search!Combo51 = year (i.e. 2011, 2012, 2013 etc.)
```

When I make my selections on the form I get a window that asks me to enter the value for Combo 46 and the committee list displays all records for that individual and not just transactions with the year I entered.  I would expect it to not come up with a pop-up at all but instead take the value from Combo46 in the Transactions table and compare it to the value entered in Combo51.

[image: screenshot1]

[image: screenshot2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's too long and unclear for a comment, so I use this anwser space:

I suppose that the table column Transactions.Combo46 does not exist, so Transactions.Combo46 is popuped by Access for Input, it should be Transactions.Year or something meaning this:

```
SELECT Transactions.[Committee Name]
FROM Transactions
GROUP BY Transactions.[Committee Name], Transactions.[Employee Name]
HAVING (((Transactions.[Employee Name])=Forms!Search!Combo40)
And (((Transactions.Year)=Forms!Search!Combo51)))
```

Answer (score 2):

What jacouh says is surely the answer (i.e., your SQL is referring to `Combo46` as a member of `Transactions` when it is a member of `Forms!Search`). As an appendum, I'd simplify things a bit like this:

(1) Name the combo boxes something sensible (e.g. `cboName` and `cboYear`) rather than leaving them as `Combo40` and `Combo51` (yuck!).

(2) The `GROUP BY` seems unnecessary to me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Committee Name] FROM Transactions
WHERE ([Employee Name] = Forms!Search!cboName) AND ([Year] = Forms!Search!cboYear)
```